# How to set custom directory for installation of R packages

Tags: r, package, installation

How do I set a custom directory to install R packages? Is it simply the following?

```
install.packages(c("data.table", "tidyverse"), destdir = "C:/Users/stackinator/Documents/R-libraries")
```

I'm not sure if my slashes are in the right direction (Windows 7) and does my destination directory need to be in quotes?

I know I can setup this in my .Renviron file, but I'm more concerend with individual package(s) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your library path using `.libPaths("/home/test_folder/packages/")`

Comment: whenever you want to redirect to this location you can use above function.

Comment: Like for new session you want to use all packages installed at  /home/test_folder/packages/ then you can simply set .libPaths(/home/test_folder/packages/) before running script